# When cola.js fails, what's a fast way to find out what went wrong?

Tags: debugging, cytoscape.js, webcola

When cola.js fails, how do you find out what went wrong?

I don't have a minimal reproducible example, because that will likely take hours of debugging to make, and if I had it, then it wouldn't be an example of what I'm asking about. I'm hoping to hear of a way to *quickly* find out what's gone wrong. Presumably it's some bad data in my graph. But how can I tell what the bad data is?

The screenshot below illustrates a typical situation where something has gone wrong. Various NaNs are reported, there are a bunch of Uncaught TypeErrors, and an Assertion fails. There are a whole lot of local variables, all named with a single letter. Clicking and looking at them shows that a NaN got into a coordinate somewhere, as suggested by the previous error messages. It looks like sometime earlier, something got a `null` when it needed some sort of list-like data structure. How can I quickly find out what was the bad data that got into the graph?

I'm using `cola.v3.min.js`.

[image: Screenshot of error shown in console of Chrome debugger]

---

### Details

I'm looking for a general approach to finding this kind of error, but here's the specific data that produced the errors in this example. Each line is the argument passed to `cy.add()` (as suggested by Stepan T.—and printing out everything passed to `cy.add()` might turn out to be the first step of the answer!).

```
{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":1,"label":"Workspace","parent":[]},"position":{"x":45,"y":0}}
{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":2,"label":"Target(121)","parent":[1]},"position":{"x":5,"y":0}}
{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":3,"label":"WantFullySourced","parent":[]},"position":{"x":50,"y":0}}
{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":4,"label":"Brick(120)","parent":[1]},"position":{"x":10,"y":0}}
{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":5,"label":"Avail","parent":[]},"position":{"x":55,"y":0}}
{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":6,"label":"Brick(1)","parent":[1]},"position":{"x":15,"y":0}}
{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":7,"label":"Avail","parent":[]},"position":{"x":60,"y":0}}
{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":8,"label":"Brick(2)","parent":[1]},"position":{"x":20,"y":0}}
{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":9,"label":"Avail","parent":[]},"position":{"x":65,"y":0}}
{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":10,"label":"Brick(3)","parent":[1]},"position":{"x":25,"y":0}}
{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":11,"label":"Avail","parent":[]},"position":{"x":70,"y":0}}
{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":12,"label":"Brick(4)","parent":[1]},"position":{"x":30,"y":0}}
{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":13,"label":"Avail","parent":[]},"position":{"x":75,"y":0}}
{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":14,"label":"Brick(5)","parent":[1]},"position":{"x":35,"y":0}}
{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":15,"label":"Avail","parent":[]},"position":{"x":80,"y":0}}
{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":16,"label":"NumericalRelationScout","parent":[1]},"position":{"x":40,"y":0}}
{"group":"nodes","data":{"id":17,"label":"OperandView","parent":[1]},"position":{"x":0,"y":0}}
{"group":"edges","data":{"id":"2.member_of.1.members","source":2,"source_port_label":"member_of","target":1,"target_port_label":"members","weight":0.5}}
{"group":"edges","data":{"id":"4.member_of.1.members","source":4,"source_port_label":"member_of","target":1,"target_port_label":"members","weight":0.5}}
{"group":"edges","data":{"id":"6.member_of.1.members","source":6,"source_port_label":"member_of","target":1,"target_port_label":"members","weight":0.5}}
{"group":"edges","data":{"id":"8.member_of.1.members","source":8,"source_port_label":"member_of","target":1,"target_port_label":"members","weight":0.5}}
{"group":"edges","data":{"id":"10.member_of.1.members","source":10,"source_port_label":"member_of","target":1,"target_port_label":"members","weight":0.5}}
{"group":"edges","data":{"id":"12.member_of.1.members","source":12,"source_port_label":"member_of","target":1,"target_port_label":"members","weight":0.5}}
{"group":"edges","data":{"id":"14.member_of.1.members","source":14,"source_port_label":"member_of","target":1,"target_port_label":"members","weight":0.5}}
{"group":"edges","data":{"id":"16.member_of.1.members","source":16,"source_port_label":"member_of","target":1,"target_port_label":"members","weight":0.5}}
{"group":"edges","data":{"id":"17.member_of.1.members","source":17,"source_port_label":"member_of","target":1,"target_port_label":"members","weight":0.5}}
{"group":"edges","data":{"id":"3.taggees.2.tags","source":3,"source_port_label":"taggees","target":2,"target_port_label":"tags","weight":0.5}}
{"group":"edges","data":{"id":"2.support_from.3.support_to","source":2,"source_port_label":"support_from","target":3,"target_port_label":"support_to","weight":2}}
{"group":"edges","data":{"id":"3.support_from.2.support_to","source":3,"source_port_label":"support_from","target":2,"target_port_label":"support_to","weight":2}}
{"group":"edges","data":{"id":"5.taggees.4.tags","source":5,"source_port_label":"taggees","target":4,"target_port_label":"tags","weight":0.5}}
{"group":"edges","data":{"id":"4.support_from.5.support_to","source":4,"source_port_label":"support_from","target":5,"target_port_label":"support_to","weight":2}}
{"group":"edges","data":{"id":"7.taggees.6.tags","source":7,"source_port_label":"taggees","target":6,"target_port_label":"tags","weight":0.5}}
{"group":"edges","data":{"id":"6.support_from.7.support_to","source":6,"source_port_label":"support_from","target":7,"target_port_label":"support_to","weight":2}}
{"group":"edges","data":{"id":"9.taggees.8.tags","source":9,"source_port_label":"taggees","target":8,"target_port_label":"tags","weight":0.5}}
{"group":"edges","data":{"id":"8.support_from.9.support_to","source":8,"source_port_label":"support_from","target":9,"target_port_label":"support_to","weight":2}}
{"group":"edges","data":{"id":"11.taggees.10.tags","source":11,"source_port_label":"taggees","target":10,"target_port_label":"tags","weight":0.5}}
{"group":"edges","data":{"id":"10.support_from.11.support_to","source":10,"source_port_label":"support_from","target":11,"target_port_label":"support_to","weight":2}}
{"group":"edges","data":{"id":"13.taggees.12.tags","source":13,"source_port_label":"taggees","target":12,"target_port_label":"tags","weight":0.5}}
{"group":"edges","data":{"id":"12.support_from.13.support_to","source":12,"source_port_label":"support_from","target":13,"target_port_label":"support_to","weight":2}}
{"group":"edges","data":{"id":"15.taggees.14.tags","source":15,"source_port_label":"taggees","target":14,"target_port_label":"tags","weight":0.5}}
{"group":"edges","data":{"id":"14.support_from.15.support_to","source":14,"source_port_label":"support_from","target":15,"target_port_label":"support_to","weight":2}}
```

The object passed to `cy.layout()` had a circular structure, so `JSON.stringify()` wouldn't print it. Adding the `getCircularReplacer()` function recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53731154/1393162) seemed to crash the browser. But manually removing elements from the layout object exposed the error: in a relative `alignment` constraint (documented under `API` [here](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-cola)), I had an offset of `'0'` where I needed a `0`, i.e. a string where a number was needed.

OK, happily that problem is now fixed. That still leaves the original question: is there a faster way to find errors like that? (The static-typing advocates are surely cackling by now.)

Comment: Can you show us an example data set, where these errors occur? Also, what is the property next? Do you use it in the cytoscape stylesheet or in the cola.js settings?

Comment: @StephanT. The `next` property is invoked by the function `findYNeighbors` deep in cola.js, apparently after trying to parse something with a regular expression (line 3712 of cola.js). My own code has no `next` anywhere. I figure the error probably occurred much earlier, in some little goof somewhere in my data. About the data set: is there a convenient way to print out the data set to see where an error might be? That itself might be the answer to this question. :)

Comment: Well, you have to call `cy.add(...)` somewhere, right? Eiter print that out in the console or print out whatever you put into the elements property of cytoscape

Comment: Look at these links for better explanations: [elements](https://js.cytoscape.org/#getting-started/specifying-basic-options) or [cy.add()](https://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.add)

Comment: @StephanT. I just posted all the data passed through `cy.add()`. In just a moment, I'll add the dictionary passed to `cy.layout()`.

Comment: @StephanT. Hmm, `JSON.stringify()` is complaining that the layout dictionary is a circular structure. I'm now googling to see how to print it out anyway…

Comment: One question though: Do you add the nodes/edges with cy.add() one by one or in a batch? I tried it [here](https://codepen.io/steevokovsky/pen/ExaaWYQ) and it seems to work with a few adjustments

Comment: @StephanT. One by one. Thanks for checking the nodes/edges, though! I just solved it moments ago: the error was in the layout object, now explained in the question. Is there some way to do something analogous to a static type check to find little mistakes like that early?

Comment: Maybe this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46257042/handle-errors-with-cytoscape-js) would help?